# How to apply css to only numbers in a text inside/or any <p><p> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts, numbers

I am Using a Regional language unicode font-face in my site but the numbers are not looking good.

So I want to apply new font-style or css to numbers only..

please help

Comment: Can you please provide your code or show the demo using fiddle.net

Comment: You cannot apply a css to text nodes, so you will have to wrap the number in some elements like span to style it

Comment: If some (important) characters do not look good in the font you have chosen, you should first look for a better font, secondly try and find a more suitable font, and thirdly ask (somewhere, not at SO) for help in finding an adequate font.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela.. I have only 2 options for font-face selection which support all browsers including ie (Local Language) so there is no other alternatives.

Answer (score 27):

This can be done using CSS's [`unicode-range` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css-fonts-3-20131003/#unicode-range-desc) which exists within `@font-face`.

The numbers 0 to 9 exist in Unicode within the range [`U+0030` to `U+0039`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm). So what you'll need to do is include a font alongside your existing font which specifically targets this range:

```css
@font-face { 
    font-family: 'My Pre-Existing Font';
    ...
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My New Font Which Handles Numbers Correctly';
    ...
    unicode-range: U+30-39;
}
```

The result of this will be that every instance of Unicode characters `U+0030` (0) through to `U+0039` (9) will be displayed in the font which specifically targets that range, and every other character will be in your current font.

Comment: This is a very nice solution but you might want to implement a javascript fallback if browser doesn't support unicode-range... As far as I know its a pretty new specification.

Comment: [`unicode-range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-range) isn’t supported by Firefox or by IE versions up to IE 8.

Comment: Depending on what “number” means, you might need to add “.”, “,”, “’”, “-”, “−”, “+”, etc., and then you would have problems, since they may appear outside numbers, too. The rule given is as such OK for unsigned integers (digit sequences).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela..Ok..Thank you..Let me try..(Y)

Comment: Would it be possible to give a working demo of this? e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/e0owrwne/

Comment: @geotheory see my answer for more clarification http://stackoverflow.com/a/40088765/842386

Comment: This code worked for me, Thanks

Comment: Incredible. For anyone wondering how to make your project recognize these two fonts, you gotta do something like `font-family: "My Pre-Existing Font", "My New Font Which Handles Numbers Correctly";`

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap all numbers in p tags with a `<span class="number">`:

CSS

```css
.number {
   font-family: Verdana;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('p').html(function(i, v){
    return v.replace(/(\d)/g, '<span class="number">$1</span>');
});
```

But personally, I would go with James suggestion ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/ZzBN9/

Comment: I know it's late, but what about `return v.replace(/(\d+)/g, etc...` ? That groups `12` and `1234` together into one span, instead of putting a span on each digit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to apply CSS to all numbers specifically. In each number tag you could add the attribute `class='number'` and then in the CSS you could add

```css
.number {
   font-family: arial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better with this

```
$('p').html(function(i, v){
    return v.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span class="number">$1</span>');
});
```

With + you avoid one span per complete number (span for 321), not one per each number found (span for 3 for 2 and for 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex replace and detect the numbers then add the class

**following code:**

```js
$('p').html(function(i,c) {
    return c.replace(/\d+/g, function(v){
    return "<span class='numbers'>" + v + "</span>";
    });
});
```

```css
.numbers
{
color:red;
font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
View 11 new out of 11 message(s) in your inbox
</p>
```