# CSS: Styling numbers and text with different fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'd like that all the numbers and all the punctuation in my website have a font-family, while the rest of the text has another.
(Example: numbers and punctuation in Arial and text in Tahoma)

I could do it for each of them, but they are A LOT, so this is not an option.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Can't be done in CSS,

Comment: what if you use a font editor and you create a new font where the dots/numbers are arial and text is tahoma, then create webfonts from it and just use it as a body font?

Comment: Actually it can using `unicode-range` but I wouldn't as it's still experimental - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-range

Comment: @passatgt or maybe Tahoma webfont without numbers and punctation so the browser will substitute the lacking characters with the second font listed in font-family? (I'm not sure it would work, but I think it should).

Comment: yep thats also a good solution

Comment: @pawel How do I do it?

Comment: You could use FontSquirrel which allows to select characters to be included in the generated webfont.

Answer (score 35):

In my case the website was half done and then I needed to change font of all the numbers across the site. I need to change all the numbers to Oxygen font. This is how I did it.

```
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Oxygen';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Oxygen'), local('Oxygen-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/oxygen/v5/LC4u_jU27qpsdszDEgeU_3-_kf6ByYO6CLYdB4HQE-Y.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+30-39;
}
```

And then replaced the `font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;` to `font-family: "Oxygen", "Poppins", sans-serif;`

The new font-family style will apply Oxygen font to all the text but we have restricted Oxygen fonts to be applied to 0-9 numbers only using the [unicode-range](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css-fonts-3-20131003/#unicode-range-desc) property. for all other text except numbers, Poppins font will be applied.

Note: U+30-39 is the range of 0-9 numbers.

Comment: this was very helpful for a website that was completely done

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I found of doing it is just **adding &text012345689 to the end of your @import url** that you get from Google Fonts, like this:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@200&display=swap&text=0123456789");
```

Then you can add another one that you will use **for your text**, you import it just like a normal import:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
```

And then finally in your css you can just simply do this and it will work:

```
body {
  font-family: "Inconsolata", "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
```

**This will apply the "Inconsolata" font to all of your numbers, and the "Montserrat" font to all of your other text.**

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

While creating a utility class might work if you need to change 1-2 instances, this seems like the best solution for changing all numerals across your site.

Thank you!

Comment: @esitarz no problem man, glad i could help you!

Answer (score 1):

You can set one `font-family` for your `body` i.e. Tahoma, and then wrap any of your numbers and punctuation marks inside a `<span>` tag, for e.g. `<span class="numbers"></span>` and then set a different font-family for the span tag using CSS like this:

```
.numbers {
     font-family: Arial;
}
```

Here's an example:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}
.numbers {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet <span class="numbers">123-456-789</span>. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum
dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. <span class="numbers">"</span>Lorem ipsum dolor ismet<span class="numbers">"</span>. Hello World<span class="numbers">???????</span>
```

Comment: `I could do it for each of them, but they are A LOT, so this is not an option.` OP Said that adding a span to every number or punctuation isn't an option.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to create 2 classes, one with Arial and one in Tahoma. And then asign the class of what element you want.